# OBJLoaderのloader.loadの外部から情報を取得したい

Tags: three.js

やりたいことは、
https://codepen.io/hisamikurita/pen/NWppvZe
上記サイトのジオメトリをOBJLoaderで読み込んだデータに変更したいというものです。

ちょっと違いますが下記サイトを参考にしてみましたが読み込みまでは出来ても外部にプロパティーを渡せない状況です。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406243/three-js-how-to-use-objects-childs-property-outside-loader-load

js自体に中途半端な知識しかないため質問自体が不明瞭かもしれません。
「こういう情報がないと答えられない」といった不足分等あればご教示頂ければ幸いです。

何卒宜しくお願い致します。